How to set custom header using foundry?
On etherjs you can send a custom header as follows.
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const connection = {
    url: "https://custom.rpc.url.com",
    headers: [ "Authorization": "SOME_API_KEY" ],
};      
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(connection);

async function main() {
    const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
    console.log(blockNumber);
}

On hardhat you can send it as follows.
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    // For localhost network
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337,
    },
    customNetwork: {
      chainId: chainId,
      url: "https://custom.rpc.url.com",
      httpHeaders: {
        "Authorization": SOME_API_KEY
      }
      accounts: [privateKey],
    }
  }
};

How do I do something similar in foundry?

An option to set httpHeaders while defining rpc_endpoints doesn't seem to be available in Foundry yet.
But, if your RPC-URL supports the API-key to be appended at the end of the url. Then, you can define the same in the foundry.toml file, like:
[rpc_endpoints]
customNetwork = "https://custom.rpc.url.com/${SOME_API_KEY}"

Provided that SOME_API_KEY is defined as an environment variable.
Then, you can use the same while running any command, by using it with the --rpc-url flag like:
forge create ContractName --rpc-url customNetwork --interactive

